# Why are my Wordpress widgets not saving?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a 3.3 Wordpress install that uses the XWidgets plugin. The widgets (especially text widgets) will not save new instances, and Wordpress displays the default widgets in the sidebar.

Apparently, this is a widespread problem, and has been linked to the use of uppercase characters in the widget id. The best fix I have found ( http://core.trac.wordpress.org/attachment/ticket/6949/widget_id.diff ) is to make the widgets.php file contain all lowercase. The link above contains a patch. As I understand it, I no longer want widgets.php to check to see if the id is all lowercase.

Unfortunately, I do not know how to implement the patch. Is it just commenting out the line starting with "$id ="? I can edit the files with Notepad++ and have access through FTP.

Here is the code from widgets.php:

```
function wp_register_sidebar_widget($id, $name, $output_callback, $options = array()) { 
global $wp_registered_widgets; 

$id = strtolower($id); 


if ( empty($output_callback) ) { 
unset($wp_registered_widgets[$id]); 
return; 


function wp_register_widget_control($id, $name, $control_callback, $options = array())     { 
global $wp_registered_widget_controls; 

$id = strtolower($id); 

( empty($control_callback) ) { 
unset($wp_registered_widget_controls[$id]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: The ticket ([#6949](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/6949)) this patch refers to was integrated into WordPress 4 years ago so it is unlikely that you need to apply the patch.

To manually apply [the patch](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/attachment/ticket/6949/widget_id.diff), add in the green lines (some patches have red lines you need to remove). If you are comfortable with the commanline then you can use the [patch command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_%28Unix%29) to do this automatically.

Comment: Much appreciated. In that case, I'm still stuck as to why the widgets aren't saving. It appears from message boards that others have had the same problem as recently as this year and last. I may need to check out the WP forum. I appreciate this answer and will accept it for the question. If anyone else has insight as to what the problem might be, feel free to comment.